# ssh works but not scp - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, scp

I am able to ssh into a remote server

```
ssh -i "C:\Users\kong\Documents\prl.ppk" haziq@10.0.1.111
```

but not able to scp

```
scp -i "C:\Users\kong\Documents\prl.ppk" kong@10.0.1.111:~/home_nfs/kong/script/train.py "./script"
```

but get this message

```
Load key "C:\\Users\\kong\\Documents\\prl.ppk": invalid format
Permission denied (publickey).
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/854208/ssh-suddenly-returning-invalid-format) seems relevant. What’s the content of key_name? What version of OpenSSH did you use to create the key?

Comment: @Ramhound should I paste the contents in my original post?